# Is there a faster method for Poincare section plotting in Wolfram Mathematica without repeated NDSolve evaluations at every integer m?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am trying to plot the Poincare section. Is there any other method where I get results faster? I use Table to find points at an integer multiple of \phi, making NDSolve evaluate the solution for every integer m. Can I find the points at all integer m without evaluating NDSolve every time?

```
time = 10000; points = Flatten[Table[
Last[Reap[NDSolve[
   {34*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]*Cos[\[Psi][t]] + 
      34*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*
       Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
      4*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*
       Sin[2*\[Phi][t]] + Sin[\[Theta][t]]*
       Sin[\[Psi][t]]*(8*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 
        17) == 0, 2*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*
      (13*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] + 
       3*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]) == 
     Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*
      (26*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
       12*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 13), 
    Cos[\[Theta][t]]*(10*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][
          t] + 4*Cos[2*\[Psi][t]]*
         Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 5) + 
      10*Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t] == 
     (Cos[2*\[Theta][t]] + 3)*Sin[2*\[Psi][t]]*
      Sin[2*\[Phi][t]], \[Phi][0] == 0, 
    \[Theta][0] == 15/10, \[Psi][0] == 15/10, 
    WhenEvent[Mod[\[Phi][t], m*Pi] == 0, 
     Sow[{ArcSin[Sin[\[Psi][t]]], \[Theta][t]}]]}, 
   {\[Theta][t], \[Phi][t], \[Psi][t]}, {t, 0, time}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 1/50]]], {m, 1000}], 2]; plot = ListPlot[points]
```

I tried to reap data for multiple integer m by using Table command within WhenEvent, but it didn't work.